# Alternatives to MetaX?

Tags: macos, itunes, software-recommendation, metadata, dvd

I'm trying to rip some DVDs on my Mac, the boxset for a TV show, using Handbrake. I'd also like to automatically fetch metadata - show name, episode name, etc. But MetaX isn't getting any metadata for me for this particular TV program. Any other Mac apps I can use that do similar?

Comment: What sort of metadata are you hoping for that it won't provide?

Comment: Name of show, episode, description, season #, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Some that I've found:

- [iFlicks.app](http://www.iflicksapp.com)
- [Vidalin](http://www.hutsongroup.com/Hutson_Group/Vidalin.html)
- [iDentify](http://identify2.arrmihardies.com)

I've yet to find one that does *everything* I want.  iFlicks.app comes close, but the feature I want that's missing is the ability to tag chapters.  You can always use more than one app, but I don't like the idea of different programs overwriting my metadata.

Comment: iFlicks is the best I've encountered. Recommended.

Comment: I use iDentify pretty religiously. I'll have to take a look into iFlicks. I wish they had a free trial run.

Comment: [MetaZ](http://griff.github.io/metaz/) is the spiritual successor to MetaX, and I just tested it on macOS Sierra successfully. Not that iDentify is no longer maintained, Vidalin points to some expired domain, and iFlicks seems somewhat minimally maintained (as of 2016).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr). Hands down, the best I've tried.

Comment: Right, I'm already using Handbrake to rip. But that has nothing to do with automatically fetching metadata. I'll edit the question to clarify.