# Is there an AppleScript or Automator action to quickly edit Info for Video in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, applescript, automator

I ripped the DVD set of a television series to my iMac. But now, the filenames are weird and there is no meta info.

In Automator, I see there is an action to edit Info for a song. That's great, but it doesn't really work for TV Shows - it won't handle the stuff that you'd see in the "Video" tab when viewing Info in iTunes.

Is there an Automator action for this that I can use? If not, AppleScript?

Comment: Would [iTag](http://www.itagsoftware.com/compatibility.php) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible on iTunes, here's a example

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with i in (get selection)
        tell i
            set episode number to 1
            set episode ID to "blah"
            set season number to 1
            set show to "blah"
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files are MP4s, you can use [MetaX](http://www.kerstetter.net/index.php/projects/software/metax) for this.

Comment: If you could add any insight to this question, it would be helpful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/alternatives-to-metax